# Divison in a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was working on a linear algebra problem in F121 (i.e the finite field with 121 elements) in which I had to multiply a matrix by 1/4. The answer is shown in the picture. I'm am very confused to how this was reached. Any help is appreciated
[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOZg7.png)

Comment: Do you know how to find 1/4 in $F_{121}?$

Comment: As a warm up problem, what's the multiplicative inverse of $4$ in the field $\mathbb Z_{11}$?

Comment: @littleO its 3 but other than brute forcing it is there a faster to way to find it

Comment: @saulspatz no, Euclid algorithm or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field $F_{121}$ is a quadratic extension of $F_{11}.$  The elements of $F_{121}$ are usually represented as polynomials of degree less than two with coefficients in $F_{11}$ but in this case, all the elements we see are constants.  That means that we are actually working in $F_{11},$ so it's just arithmetic modulo $11.$  Yes, $1/4=3,$ and for a problem like this, brute force is as good as anything else.

Now just do the arithmetic modulo $11,$ and you'll get the answer shown.

Comment: awesome thanks but given Fp^n would I just find the inverse in Fp and use that for the problem.

Comment: You can do it that way in this case, because $4$ is in the prime field, and that is a subfield of the extension field, of course.   So, if you were doing the problem in $F_{11^3},$ you'd still have 1/4 = 3.  But if the scalar multiplying the matrix were $1/(4+x),$ say, then you'd have to work in the extension field ($F_{121}$ or $F_{11^3}$ as the case may be.)